# Displaying and Hiding Divs regarding state of page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, show-hide

I was wondering how you would go about showing, and then hiding divs regarding the state of the page.

For example, I have an upload button, once the file is uploaded I want the page to switch to the next method, which will display another "page" and pull the relevant information from what is needed.

my current "viewstate" code is

```
<script runat="server"> 

//This template is being built to allow the viewstates to be displayed and allow them to be hidden
//or shown at the same time. The buttons are being added so we can test whether they will
//be hidden on page use
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string viewStateDisplay = "ViewState 2 is now being displayed";
            if (ViewState["PageState"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["PageState"] = viewStateDisplay;
            }
        }

    }

    //button that shows the label string
   protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        lblString.Text = ViewState["PageState"].ToString();
        lblString.Visible = true;      
   }

   //button that hides the div, changing "lblstring" or adding more should be able to hide 
   //or show whatever methods / objects we want
   private void Close(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
         lblString.Visible = !lblString.Visible;
         lblString.Visible = false;
   }


</script>

<!-- The following section will include all the html and forms etc !-->
<div>

ViewState Data: <b><asp:Label ID="lblString" runat="server"/></b>
<asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Get ViewState Data" OnClick="btnClick_Click"/>
<asp:Button ID="Closeform" runat="server" Text ="Hide PageState" OnClick="Close" />

</div>
```

I have a feeling I'll have to set both steps visible as false, then set each method a number based on the position I want it to appear.

Such as

```
If request ("thing") then methodName
end if

if request ("second thing") then viewstate new method 

if nothing viewstate 1

step1.visible = false
step2.visible = false
```

But I'm not sure how to turn that into workable C# code, using my original code and implementing my own methods into this, Help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am getting your problem, that you want to switch the pages after your file upload gets completed, then for this, you can follow one of the approach as:

Use a hidden button as:

```
<asp:Button ID="HdnButtonID" runat="server" Style="visibility: hidden" OnClick="moveToNextPage" />
```

On click of your upload button, call a javascript function and Fire the button event as:

```
function onClickofUploadButton()
    {
        FireEvent(HdnButtonID);
    }
```

This will fire your server side code where you can save the data in Session and redirect to a new page.

Comment: I've been told I've got to achieve this by only using one page, and instead moving from div to div, hiding and then displaying the next section.

For example, when the file upload is complete, that div / method must be hidden, and replaced by the next section. Due to the way it is being handled on the server / CMS alongside the backend code it requires, I was told it's best to keep everything in one web user control.